# Continue enumeration on IEnumerable

Tags: c#

Using `yield` keyword we are able to only calculate the needed amount of items in the `IEnumerable`. I have set up a test, in which I was generating a number of items and then I wanted to generate one more. What I expected was the function to start where it ended, in this case on the `10000000` iteration and only iterate once more to `10000001`. Please check out this piece of code:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var naturalNumbers = GetNaturalNumbers();

    var executionTime = GetExecutionTime(() => naturalNumbers.ElementAt(10000000));
    Console.WriteLine($"Time elapsed: {executionTime}");

    executionTime = GetExecutionTime(() => naturalNumbers.ElementAt(10000001));
    Console.WriteLine($"Time elapsed: {executionTime}");
}

public static IEnumerable<int> GetNaturalNumbers()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Running GetNaturalNumbers() from the beginning");
    for(int value = 0;; value++)
    {
        yield return value;
    }
}

public static System.TimeSpan GetExecutionTime(Action action)
{
    var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    action();

    stopwatch.Stop();
    return stopwatch.Elapsed;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Running GetNaturalNumbers() from the beginning
Time elapsed: 00:00:00.0618548
Running GetNaturalNumbers() from the beginning
Time elapsed: 00:00:00.0562454
```

The time elapsed in the second call is lower and made me guess that it's only because processor optimization. The function is called twice from the beginning.

What's the real reason behind this output? Is it possible to continue the iteration from the point at which we ended in the first call?

**Edit:**

Now I see that my example isn't good enough. Suppose we have a very complex and time consuming operation in the `GetNaturalNumbers()` function. I was expecting for the second call to start the enumeration from the `10000000`'th element and not need to calculate all of it once again. I expected a significant performance improvement in the second call.

---

*Another example:*

Imagine a book with many pages, in which you don't want to get all of the pages at once, but only the amount that the reader needs. When the reader turns the page we would get it without having to calculate all the previous ones.

Comment: Is your question why it's enumerated twice?

Comment: The second operation is probably quicker because you only did a single run, or the first one did the actual "warming up" of your code. Benchmarking is more complex then just running things like this. How many times did you run it? Was it in release or debug mode? etc. etc.

Comment: If you have an `IEnumerable<T>` then every time you enumerate it, it will start at the beginning. (Note that some enumerables don't like being enumerated more than once, but yours is fine.)

Comment: Try calling the methods five or six times each to "warm up" and _then_ do a comparison run with another five or six times each. Then take the mean time to get a more accurate measure. Also do a full `GC.Collect` between each run, just to be sure. -- or use a benchmarking tool like https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/overview.html (no affiliation).

Comment: So, your question is in fact: How can I resume the iteration on an `IEnumerable` using `Yield`. Is it?

Comment: @Stefan I think you got it right

Comment: @Rasmond Then my answer tells you how to achieve that.

Comment: If you want to remember where you were, you need to cache the `IEnumerator` somehow. As there is no version of ElementAt that take a enumerator, either make one or use DavidG answer and manually use the IEnumerator.

Comment: PS the IEnumerator has no index. It's you that will decide if a given enumerator will find 10001 going forward or if it should reset and go from the start. It's perhaps time to consider using an IList instead and use the index.^^

Comment: Your book example works, because all pages already exist (are "calculated"), and you can simply skip them, or better yet, access them by index because they are usually neatly sorted and even marked. An `IEnumerable<T>` is like a book you don't know how many pages are in. And every time you're done reading, the book closes. So if you want to get back to where you were, you need to find the page you left off. So you need to skip through all the pages before that until you reach the one you want. If the book was an `IList<T>` (as most are), then you could access by index directly.

Answer (score 5):

Everyone else seems to be talking about the speed, which doesn't seem to be your real question.

You are thinking that after you execute:

`var executionTime = GetExecutionTime(() => naturalNumbers.ElementAt(10000000));`

And then execute:

`executionTime = GetExecutionTime(() => naturalNumbers.ElementAt(10000001));`

That it is supposed to know you already did it for `10000000` so it should only do 1 iteration of the loop.

That's simply not how it works.  Your yield return will cut short the loop and return the value you need, but both of these statements are completely independent and it is going to run:

`for(int value = 0;; value++)`

Both times.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant

Comment: We all know that it's doing the enumeration twice. This answer is just a re statement of the context of the question. "_What's the real reason behind this output?_" answer=> You're not doing the benchmark correctly.

Comment: @xdtTransform I think it's actually even worse, the question is about how *not* to enumerate twice and instead carry on from the previous point, this answer doesn't attempt to answer that at all.

Comment: @DavidG, Totaly agreed. But IMO, that just a miss understanding. Neither understood the comment, (as this was the first answer they can't be talking about other answers). It's re statement, I use this every day on my wife. Everytime she think i answered her question.

Comment: @xdtTransform Let me just clarify the last few sentences of my original question. 1 part of output is the execution times and the other is that the function was called from the beginning. Both of these factors matter, because I expected the second call to be significantly faster and not print the line. My question was not: why the second call was faster, it was: why it is **not** faster. This question answers that, although it doesn't say how to modify it like DavidG's answer does

Comment: Second call is not faster. And it's doing the enumeration "From the start" as your `Console.WriteLine` proves it. The reason why is in the provided out put.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to *not* iterate over the same enumerable twice. To do this, you need to get a bit more manual with your handling of the values. Calling `GetNaturalNumbers` twice will give you two distinct enumerators, meaning your second operation just loops over all 10000001 items. You could do something like this which gets the [`IEnumerator<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1.getenumerator?view=netframework-4.8) for the enumerable and manually moves over the incoming stream of numbers:

```
var enumerable = GetNaturalNumbers();
var enumerator = enumerable.GetEnumerator();

var fistElementToFind = 10000000;

for(var i = 0; i <= fistElementToFind; i++)
{
    enumerator.MoveNext();
}

var firstValue = enumerator.Current;
enumerator.MoveNext();
var nextValue = enumerator.Current;

Console.WriteLine($"First value: {firstValue}");
Console.WriteLine($"Next value: {nextValue}");
```

Answer (score 1):

Each `ElementAt` calls are independent ones. All `IEnumerable` extension methods are implemented so that they obtain a new enumerator.

If you use ReSharper you might also get a warning saying

> Possible multiple enumerations of IEnumerable `naturalNumbers`

On the other hand, the `ElementAt` implementation really tries to do its best to retrieve the result quickly if possible. If the collection implements the `IList<T>` interface, then it will call its indexer in the first place. Otherwise, it uses the ultimate fallback mechanism by obtaining the enumerator.

> What's the real reason behind this output?

Just ignore the first result, which also includes JIT time. To me [the result](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0De1QG) seems to be ok.

> Is it possible to continue the iteration from the point at which we ended in the first call?

Obtain the enumerator manually as per @DavidG's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own ElementAt extension method instead. It's an improvement over @DavidG's answer.

```
static class IEnumerableExtension
{
    public static T ElementAtRetainPos<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, EnumeratorWithPos<T> enumeratorWithPos, int elementToFind)
    {
        if (elementToFind < enumeratorWithPos.EnumeratorPosition)
        {
            enumeratorWithPos.Enumerator = source.GetEnumerator();
        }
        for (var i = enumeratorWithPos.EnumeratorPosition; i < elementToFind; i++)
        {
            enumeratorWithPos.Enumerator.MoveNext();
        }
        enumeratorWithPos.EnumeratorPosition = elementToFind;
        return enumeratorWithPos.Enumerator.Current;
    }

    public static EnumeratorWithPos<T> GetEnumeratorWithPos<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        return new EnumeratorWithPos<T>()
        {
            Enumerator = source.GetEnumerator()
        };
    }
}

public class EnumeratorWithPos<T> : IDisposable
{
    private IEnumerator<T> enumerator;

    public IEnumerator<T> Enumerator
    {
        get
        {
            return enumerator;
        }
        set
        {
            enumerator = value;
            EnumeratorPosition = -1;
        }
    }
    public int EnumeratorPosition { get; set; }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Enumerator.Dispose();
    }
}
```

How to use:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var naturalNumbers = GetNaturalNumbers();
    using (var enumeratorWithPos = naturalNumbers.GetEnumeratorWithPos())
    {
        var executionTime = GetExecutionTime(() => naturalNumbers.ElementAtRetainPos(enumeratorWithPos, 10000000));
        Console.WriteLine($"Time elapsed: {executionTime}");

        executionTime = GetExecutionTime(() => naturalNumbers.ElementAtRetainPos(enumeratorWithPos, 10000001));
        Console.WriteLine($"Time elapsed: {executionTime}");

        // force reset of enumerator by moving back to the previous
        executionTime = GetExecutionTime(() => naturalNumbers.ElementAtRetainPos(enumeratorWithPos, 10000001));
        Console.WriteLine($"Time elapsed: {executionTime}");
    }
}

public static IEnumerable<int> GetNaturalNumbers()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Running GetNaturalNumbers() from the beginning");
    for(int value = 0;; value++)
    {
        yield return value;
    }
}

public static System.TimeSpan GetExecutionTime(Action action)
{
    var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    action();

    stopwatch.Stop();
    return stopwatch.Elapsed;
}
```

First time it takes 00:00:00.1565686

Second request takes 00:00:00.0001373

Comment: `IEnumerator.Reset` throws a `NotSupportedException` for iterators.

Comment: Rewrote to make this as an extension method instead.